# SQL Insert into with select from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

I have the following 3 tables, Data_Excel contains the names, address, city and source of person; Person table has the name and ID; I need to insert into person_location the address source, address, city and ID...where ID comes from person table and name that exist against the id should be matched in the data_excel table to get all the details

[image: I have the following 3 tables, Data_Excel contains the names, address, city and source of person; Person table has the name and ID; I need to insert into person_location the address source, address, city and ID...where ID comes from person table and name that exist against the id should be matched in the data_excel table to get all the details]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have a query that isn't giving the expected results?

Comment: Select A.ID,A.P_name,source,P_address,P_city,P_country
from data_excel, person A where A.name, A.ID in
(Select id,name
from person
where ID > 6566
)
I tried to select like this but got an error

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131164/oracle-insert-via-select-from-multiple-tables-where-one-table-may-not-have-a-row) which should provide the information you need to apply to your own problem.

Comment: how will i check the name matches against the id so that i get the relevant values?

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably from this part of the query `A.name, A.ID in (Select[...]`

You can try..

```
INSERT INTO person_location 
SELECT A.ID,A.P_name,source,P_address,P_city,P_country from data_excel de, person A where A.name = de.c_name;
```

If you need the `ID > 6566` condition, you can add it at the end.

```
INSERT INTO person_location 
SELECT A.ID,A.P_name,source,P_address,P_city,P_country from data_excel de, person A where A.name = de.c_name and ID > 6566;
```

Comment: Replace `source` in the `SELECT` with either `A.source` or `de.source` depending on which table you want it from.

Comment: Select A.ID, A.Name , de.source, de.P_address, de.P_city, de.P_Country
from data_excel de, person A 
where A.name = de.P_Name
and ID > 6566
This works thanks...

Comment: You're welcome. Be careful in this kind of setup though that if there are multiple ID's with the same name, it could get messy.

Comment: In that case how can i make a unique check on id+name combined?

Comment: also i tried to insert but apparently start_date is the primary key, can you please tell me how can i increment the date values?
Insert into person_location(person,address,city,country,startdate,enddate,source)
Select A.ID,de.P_address, de.P_city, de.P_Country,Select dateadd(mm,1,'01/01/1000','DD/MM/YYYY'),to_date('31/12/3999','DD/MM/YYYY'), de.source 
from data_excel de, person A 
where A.name = de.P_Name
and ID > 6566

Comment: 1) For the unique check, unless there's another column that's unique to each person and is found in both `Person` and `data_excel`, I think the only solution is to add column `ID` to `data_excel`. 2) For the dates, what is the idea exactly for incrementing `startdate`? 3) For enddate, use `STR_TO_DATE('31/12/3999','%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: the idea behind auto increment of Start date is that person name and start date combined is the primary key in the table

Comment: I try to insert data using sequence:
CREATE SEQUENCE seq
MINVALUE 6571
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 100
AND the QUERY:
INSERT INTO Person (id,Name,source)
Select (select seq.nextval from dual),p_name,source
FROM Data_Excel WHERE P_Name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM Person)
GROUP BY P_Name,P_Address,P_city,Source
HAVING count(*) < 2;

But i am facing this error:
code (02287. 00000 -  "sequence number not allowed here"
*Cause:    The specified sequence number (CURRVAL or NEXTVAL) is inappropriate
           here in the statement.
*Action:   Remove the sequence number.)

Comment: Next time, try searching for the error you get and see if any solutions work for you. For now, try this `INSERT INTO Person (id,Name,source) Select seq.nextval,p_name,source FROM Data_Excel WHERE P_Name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM Person) GROUP BY P_Name,P_Address,P_city,Source HAVING count(*) < 2;`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41631/discussion-between-rmk-and-user408437)