# Insert Multiple Tables into one Table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
 Http://i.stack.imgur.com/z0fSP.png
 Http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd3nB.png
 Http://i.stack.imgur.com/5qtRh.png
 Http://i.stack.imgur.com/01PVc.png
 Http://i.stack.imgur.com/wvibY.png



 INSERT INTO  OrderArchive                               

    (OrderNumber,OrderDate,StockItem,Quantity,UnitPrice,SalesRep,Customer,ArchiveDate)     
    SELECT "ORDER".OrderNo,
    "ORDER".OrderDate,
    Stock.StockNo||' '||Stock.StockDesc,
    Orderline.Quantity,
    Orderline.UnitPrice,
    Person.FirstName||' '||Person.Surname,
    Person.FirstName||' '||Person.Surname,
    OrderArchive.ArchiveDate
    FROM "ORDER"
    INNER JOIN Stock
        ON Stock.StockNo||' '||Stock.StockDesc = OrderAchive.StockItem
    INNER JOIN Orderline
        ON Orderline.Quantity = OrderArchive.Quantity
    INNER JOIN Orderline
        ON Orderline.UnitPrice = OrderArchive.UnitPrice
    INNER JOIN Person
        ON Person.FirstName||' '||Person.Surname = OrderArchive.SalesRep
    INNER JOIN Person       
        ON Person.FirstName||' '||Person.Surname = OrderArchive.Customer 
    WHERE "ORDER".OrderDate  < DATEADD('M',6,SYSDATE);
```

I tried to work it out first, but just couldnt manage it .... i am trying to move orders that are older than 6 months to OrderArchive...OrderArchive has OrderNo & Orderdate that come from "ORDER"Table Stock item which is a combination of StockID and Stockdesc from stock table quantity and unit cost are from orderline table salesrep and customer are from person Table and datearchived is a sysdate of the date the order was archived

Comment: Your google-foo is incredibly weak: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131164/oracle-insert-via-select-from-multiple-tables-where-one-table-may-not-have-a-row

Comment: INSERT INTO  OrderArchive (OrderNumber,OrderDate,StockItem,Quantity,UnitPrice,SalesRep,Customer,ArchiveDate)
VALUES(
(SELECT OrderNo FROM "ORDER"),
(SELECT OrderDate FROM "ORDER" WHERE Orderdate < '19-May-14'),
(SELECT StockNo||''||StockDesc FROM Stock),
(SELECT Quantity FROM OrderLine),
(SELECT UnitPrice FROM OrderLine),
(SELECT FirstName||''|| Surname FROM Person),
(SELECT FirstName||''|| Surname FROM Person),
(SELECT ArchiveDate FROM OrderArchive))
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

:

Comment: Tried that last night kept getting an error

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need a way to join the `Person` record to the `TableOrder` record. This code assumes you have a `PersonID` on the `TableOrder` table. You might have a `CustomerID` or `SalesPersonID` or something like that on your `TableOrder` table to join it to the `Person` table, but I'm not clear on that.

```
INSERT INTO ArchiveTable (col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4 etc)
    SELECT
        o.OrderNo,
        o.OrderDate,
        p.StockNo||' '||p.StockDesc,
        p.FirstName||' '|| p.Surname
    FROM TableOrder o
        INNER JOIN Person p
            ON p.PersonID = o.PersonID
    WHERE o.orderdate < DATEADD('M',12,SYSDATE)
```

Comment: Thanks Ron Smith I wanted to try work it out with a little bit of information that i gave you but i havent been able to.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are not getting the expected output from the query, because you are joining the `Person` table with both `SalesRep` and `Customer` names at the same time. Thus, only if an Order has  the same name for both `SalesRep` and `Customer`, will you get any data. Therefore, I have created different table aliases for the Person table, as below:

```
INSERT INTO  OrderArchive
    (OrderNumber,OrderDate,StockItem,Quantity,UnitPrice,SalesRep,Customer,ArchiveDate)     
SELECT 
    "ORDER".OrderNo,
    "ORDER".OrderDate,
    Stock.StockNo||' '||Stock.StockDesc,
    Orderline.Quantity,
    Orderline.UnitPrice,
    Person_SR.FirstName||' '||Person_SR.Surname,
    Person_C.FirstName||' '||Person_C.Surname,
    OrderArchive.ArchiveDate
FROM "ORDER"
INNER JOIN Stock
ON Stock.StockNo||' '||Stock.StockDesc = OrderAchive.StockItem
INNER JOIN Orderline
ON Orderline.Quantity = OrderArchive.Quantity
INNER JOIN Orderline
ON Orderline.UnitPrice = OrderArchive.UnitPrice
INNER JOIN Person Person_SR
ON Person_SR.FirstName||' '||Person_SR.Surname = OrderArchive.SalesRep
INNER JOIN Person Person_C       
ON Person_C.FirstName||' '||Person_C.Surname = OrderArchive.Customer 
WHERE "ORDER".OrderDate  < DATEADD('M',6,SYSDATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO OrderArchive (OrderNumber,OrderDate,StockItem,Quantity,UnitPrice,SalesRep,Customer)
SELECT          "ORDER".OrderNo,
                "ORDER".OrderDate,
                Stock.StockNo ||' '|| Stock.StockDesc,
                Orderline.Quantity,
                Stock.UnitCost,
                "ORDER".SalesRepID, 
                Person.FirstName||' '||Person.Surname 
 FROM Person INNER JOIN
    ("ORDER" LEFT JOIN
      (Orderline INNER JOIN Stock
      ON Orderline.StockID=Stock.StockNo)
      ON"ORDER".OrderNo=OrderLine.OrderNo)
      ON Person.PersonID="ORDER".CustomerID
      WHERE "ORDER".OrderDate < ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE,-6)
    ORDER BY "ORDER".OrderNo;

```
SELECT * FROM OrderArchive;
```

Nearly Done i just have to get SalesRepID to say firstname surname of salesrep  but mostly done :)